# Prove that $f:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, $f(m,n) = 2^m (2n+1)$ is $1-1$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{N\times N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be defined as 
$$f(m,n)=2^m(2n+1)$$ 
I want to prove that $f$ is $1-1$.

I know that I have to show that if $f(m,n)=f(p,q)$ then $m=p$ and $n=q$. Is it correct to show first from $f(m,n) = f(m,q)$ that $n=q$ and then do the same thing with $m$ and $p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not enough to show that, because it doesn't exclude the possibility that $f(0,1)=f(1,2)$ for example. Indeed, consider $f=x-y$.

You need to prove it all at once, for which you should (as indicated elsewhere) consider the prime factorization of $f(m,n)$.

Comment: I'm not sure how prime factorization is linked with this problem

Comment: $2^m(2n+1)=2^p(2q+1)$. Think about it.

Comment: 2 is a prime, so the first factor makes the result unique??

Comment: That's not really a mathematical argument yet. Why isn't $2^2 \times 2 = 2^3\times 1$ a contradiction?

Comment: because 1 is not prime??

Comment: Er, not really. If you're looking for things not being prime then obviously $2^2,2^3$ aren't prime either. Why is it that breaking a number down as $2^m(2n+1)$ is unique but $2^m( n)$ isn't (as the last example showed)?

Comment: because $2n+1>1$ ?

Comment: What about $2^4\times 2^2=2^3\times 2^3$? Think about things for a bit rather than just guessing at random!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $2^m$ is even while $2n+1$ is odd for any $m,n \in\mathbb{N}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).